# How can I add navigationbar background image to MFMailComposeViewController on ios7

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, ios7, uinavigationbar

I am using MFMailComposeViewController.I can't add navigationBar background image to MFMailComposeViewController on ios7.My Code working ios7 before .But doesn't work on ios7.How can I add navigationbar background image to MFMailComposeViewController on ios7?

```
    MFMailComposeViewController *mailCompose = [[MFMailComposeViewController alloc] init];
    mailCompose.mailComposeDelegate = self;
    [mailCompose setSubject:@"SubjectName"];
    [mailCompose setMessageBody:shareBodyString isHTML:NO];
    if ([self respondsToSelector:@selector(presentViewController:animated:completion:)])
    {
      [self presentViewController:mailCompose animated:YES completion:nil];
    } 
    else {
         [self presentModalViewController:mailCompose animated:YES];
    }

    [mailCompose.topViewController.navigationController.navigationBar setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"navigationbar-background.png"] forBarMetrics:UIBarMetricsDefault];  // working before ios7
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the Appearance Proxy. Following code will target the whole application :

```
UINavigationBar *navBar = [UINavigationBar appearance];
[navBar setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"navigationbar-background.png"] forBarMetrics:UIBarMetricsDefault];
```

If you prefer to target only in MFMailComposeViewController change the first line with this :

```
navBar = [UINavigationBar appearanceWhenContainedIn:[MFMailComposeViewController class], nil];
```

Comment: Thank you for answer @vinceBurn .today i have meeting .i will look in free time

Comment: it's not work. But it's helped me for research and find. I wrote this code and it's worked: [[UINavigationBar appearance] setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"navigationbar-background.png"] forBarPosition:UIBarPositionTopAttached barMetrics:UIBarMetricsDefault]; . but I don't understand why your code doesn't work .what is difference your code and me ? thanks

Comment: @ErhanDemirci The code I've post won't compile unless modify for your case I will update the code to be a little bit more 'generic'

Answer (score 0):

If you already customised navigation bar and also want it to apply MFMailComposeViewController, It only allows to do it with UIAppearance proxy. For iOS 7.1.1, i replaced navigation bar background but couldn't change status bar background. Also it greyed out bar button items on subsequent calls. Therefore I stop customising and tried to turn back to default navigation bar style before creating MFMailComposeViewController

```
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] setStatusBarStyle:UIStatusBarStyleDefault];
[[UINavigationBar appearance] setBarStyle:UIBarStyleDefault];
[[UINavigationBar appearance] setTintColor:nil];
[[UINavigationBar appearance] setTitleTextAttributes:[NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:[UIColor blackColor],NSForegroundColorAttributeName,[UIFont fontWithName:@"Helvetica-Bold" size:18.0], NSFontAttributeName, nil]];

 MFMailComposeViewController *mailComposer =[[MFMailComposeViewController alloc] init];
```